# What is the console command to see whether or not a character is flagged?

Tags: torchlight-2

As the title says, I know there is a console command to see whether or not a given character is flagged as a cheater or suspicious. What is the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view flag status for your own character, the console command is **doicheat**.

For other players you can tell by the red ! next to their name.